# How to perform Particle Swarm Optimization

Tags: math, optimization, computation, particles

We have been asked to do 5 or 6 iterations of particle swarm optimisation by hand for homework, but i don't really understand how and we were given no examples.

Would it be possible for someone to do the first run through for me so I can see how it works?

Explanations as each step would be fantastic.

Consider an illustrative example of a particle swarm optimisation system composed of three particles and Vmax = 10. To facilitate calculation, we will ignore the fact that r1 and r2 are random numbers and fix them to 0.5 for this exercise. The space of solutions is the two dimensional real valued space R2 and the current state of the swarm is as follows:

- Position of particles: x1 = (5,5); x2 = (8,3); x3 = (6,7);
- Individual best positions: x∗1 = (5,5); x∗2 = (7,3); x∗3 = (5,6);
- Social best position: x∗ = (5,5);
- Velocities: v1 = (2,2); v2 = (3,3); v3 = (4,4).

Comment: If I, or any other SOer, do this for you, how will that help you learn ?

Answer (score 3):

"I don't really understand how and we were given no examples". Let me add a little bit of critique to this sentence. If you're not given any examples it probably means you should be looking for examples for yourself. Have you even put "particle swarm optimization" into Google and look at some of the results? Do you expect everything in your study to be given to you?

There are many resources that explain the working of particle swarm optimization such as [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Particle_swarm_optimization), [Google Scholar](http://scholar.google.at/scholar?q=particle+swarm+optimization&hl=en&oi=scholart), [Scholarpedia](http://www.scholarpedia.org/article/Particle_swarm_optimization), or a [dedicated website](http://www.swarmintelligence.org/) to PSO. The original paper is from Kennedy and Eberhart 1995 and is the top result in the scholar search. Also there are frameworks where PSO is implemented and where you can look at how it works like [HeuristicLab](http://dev.heuristiclab.com). It's an opportunity to explore this topic.

Comment: +1: *Do you expect everything in your study to be given to you?* Programatt, things will not be given to you in your career. I'm all in favor of upper class undergrad / graduate classes that give assignments where part of the problem is that the problem to be solved is not specified. The student needs to come up with the problem.